# Calculator. Can't set floats in base of logarithms (malformed expression at token "..")

Tags: calculator, gnome-calculator

Please see the screenshot, I think it is quite self-explained )
I use [Alt] to type the base, I think "," must be subscript. However it doesn't look like..

[image]

What do I wrong?!

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. I believe the subscript function doesn't accept non-integer numbers, and therefore, you should report this as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the trick instead: `log(50) / log(1,021) = log_1,021(50)` (see screenshot)